# Heroku does not install gem

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, bundler

I have a local gem with a dependency to httparty.

Locally everything is fine.
If I push the application to heroku I do no get any error.
If I run my gem in Heroku I miss the httparty gem.

Below you can fine the status of my gems locally and remotely on Heroku
Locally:

```
:~/workspace/daemon (master)$ gem list | grep httparty 
httparty (0.11.0)
:~/workspace/daemon (master)$ cat Gemfile.lock | grep httparty
httparty (0.11.0)
httparty
:~/workspace/daemon (master)$ cat esendex-daemon.gemspec | grep httparty
spec.add_development_dependency "httparty"
```

On Heroku:

```
:~/workspace/daemon (master)$ heroku run gem list | grep httparty
:~/workspace/daemon (master)$ heroku run cat Gemfile.lock | grep httparty
httparty (0.11.0)
httparty
```

What could be the problem? 
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide Heroku "install" log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku doesn't install development dependencies

change the `spec.add_development_dependency` into `spec.add_dependency`